# How do I restructure this code so it only displays results from one column?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I got this code from a website and I am trying to tailor it to my test script.  Instead of zip, city, state I want to display company_name.  How can I modify this?

PHP:

```
 $rs = mysql_query('select company_name from names_of_companies where 
 company_name like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" 
 order by company_name asc limit 0,10', $dblink);

 $data = array();
 if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
 {
 while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
 {

 //This is the part where instead of displaying zip, city, state 
 I only want company_name, how can i do that?

 $data[] = array(
 'label' => $row['zip'] .', '. $row['city'] .' '. $row['state'] ,
 'value' => $row['zip']
 );
 }
 }
```

Comment: Change the array.  `'label' => $row['company_name'], 'value' => $row['company_name']`

Comment: And read over [the PHP manual on arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) to understand how the `$data` arrays is being appended to.  Also the [`mysql_fetch_array()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) to understand this common usage.

Comment: Can you write as an answer so i can select it? Thanks.

Comment: I'll leave it to someone else to post a full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that is what you want to have in the loop:

```
//I only want company_name, how can i do that?

$data[] = array('label' => 'Company_name', 'value'=> $row['company_name'] );
```

But if you had a hard time figuring *this* out, you will have hell of a time doing things right... I recommend stepping back, and getting familiar with [PHP](http://uk.php.net/docs.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
{
   ...
   'company_name' => $row['company_name']; // this is what you want
   ...
```

**Note that:** as quoted from [**`mysql_fetch_array`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) manual:

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the [**MySQLi**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)
>   extension should be used. See also MySQL: [choosing an API guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and
>   related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function
>   include:
>
> - [mysqli_fetch_array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).
> - [PDOStatement::fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).